# exporting vector graphics to pdf with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, itext, mschart

I am new here and new to iTextSharp and I am stuck....

I am also new to .net and pdf programming. My general programming knowledge is decent but rusty......

What I am trying to do:

- Create a Chart in Visual Studio 2012 / C# (OK)
- Save it as a bitmap to a file stream (OK)
- Create (pdf) file stream with iTextSharp and add some text (OK)
- Add the Chart bitmap filestream to the pdf filestream and write as pdf to disk (OK)

However, the bitmap result is quite poor, even with all aliasing options on. So I want to save the Chart to the filestream in vector format (OK). 
- MS IMF formats are the only vector formats supported/exported by the MS Graph Chart control. 
- iTextSharp PdfWriter only imports bitmaps, so the vector graph can not be imported.

So what are my options? Creating the graphs as raw pdf is not an option....

I read somewhere that pdfStamper supports vector graphics and I have tried but failed miserably; can not find a way to pass vector data to the pdf stream.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: *So what are my options?* - use some imaging API which can parse *MS IMF* and then do the equivalent using `PdfContentByte` methods on `writer.getDirectContent()`.